# Connecting to Analysis Services from Excel using data connection wizard and MFA - unable to obtain authentication token

Tags: excel, azure, multi-factor-authentication, azure-analysis-services

Good morning,

I have a problem getting others to connect to my tabular models using the connection wizard through Excel.

The test users and myself all have the same credentials in the active directory (we're all assigned to 'owners' under Analysis Services) - and our credentials uses MFA for authenticating. We are also both members of the Analysis Services admins.

For myself I have been able to connect by going to get data -> from database -> from analysis services. I enter the server name by copying the server name from the overview page, and I select "Use the following User Name and Password", I leave the fields blank, and I hit next. This brings up a Microsoft prompt to sign into my Microsoft account, and I am able to connect.

However, when I try this same method for other users I get 'unable to obtain the authentication token error'. Furthermore, if I try to use their username and password blank, username and password, or even the windows authentication, I get the exact same error regardless of which option we choose.

We have verified that the username in question has the exact same credentials as I do, and I even made this other party one of the Analysis Services admins to no avail.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Additional details - the test users are able to access our other databases using the same MFA credentials, and the user in question is a co-owner of the subscription as well. We also have the same credential structure across all usernames.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I  had to assign roles within Visual Studio and / or SSMS for the Analysis Services model in question, in addition to what permissions are used for Active Directory.

People did not have the necessary roles and permissions within the model itself.